# Possible for an element to 'escape' the constrained boundaries of a div with fixed dimensions and overflow:hidden?

Tags: css, overflow

One for the CSS gurus - is it possible for a div to 'escape' the constrained in the boundaries of a div with fixed dimensions and `overflow:hidden`?

Ive recreated the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Wt3q4/1/

Ive tried setting z-indexes on all the elements, and assigning the div with class `b` `position:absolute` with no joy.

Comment: That would defeat the purpose of `overflow: hidden`.

Answer (score 2):

Since `.b` is nested with an element that's `position:relative;`, setting `.b` to absolute won't do anything.  That I know of, with the element structure you have defined, there isn't going to be a CSS work around.

Without knowing more about your layout and what you're trying to accomplish, it's difficult to advise.  You could try setting up a "double container" if that makes sense, and use a jQuery function to move the element out of the `overflow:hidden;` element when you want to show it.

http://jsfiddle.net/Wt3q4/3/

**HTML**

```
<div class="a">

    <div class="b">
        <div class="c">
        </div>
    </div>    

</div>

<div id="show" class="button">Show!</div>
<div id="hide" class="button">Hide!</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.a{
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    border:3px solid #f00;
    background:#ccc;
}

.b{
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background:#ccc;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.c{
    width:50px;
    height:300px;
    border:3px solid #00f;
    background:#dad;
    margin:30px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:333;
}
.hidden{
    display: none;
}
.button {
    width: 50px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 3px solid #aaa;
    background: #ddd;
    margin: 20px;
    float: right;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#show').on('click', function(){
    $('.c').prependTo('.a');
    $('.b').addClass('hidden');
});

$('#hide').on('click', function(){
    $('.c').prependTo('.b');
    $('.b').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of CSS's block formatting context, your `div.b` is a child of `div.a`, which means that `div.a` sets the block formatting context for `div.b`.  Once you set `overflow: hidden` on the parent element, any child content that flows out of the parent content box will not be visible.

This is more apparent if you set `outline: 1px solid black` on the parent container so that you can see the extend of the content box, both with `overflow` hidden and visible.

Your question does touch on the essentials of CSS's visual formatting model.

Answer (score -1):

How about something like:

```
.menu > li > ul {
    position: absolute; /* you still need this here */
    background-color: #9F26B4;
    width: 10000000000000000px;
    margin-left: -100000px;
    padding-left: 100000px;
    list-style: none;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

This, for example, overflows the entire page from left to right (assuming that the body overflow-x is set to hidden) and then set element width to enormous width, margin it to negative left to fill any left content, and padding to the left to move object inside the element to desirable X position. What you think?

Comment: Okay, but why? This escapes the stacking context? Widths over 32768 seem excessive, but widths over 2^32 are insane. I did a quick calculation, that is 2 billion km width on a 2K 32" monitor.

Comment: @doug65536 i don't know what the name of this is, but what it does is to create a large marging that creates a lot of free space on the left, then large padding on the left that basically cancels the margin. I'm pretty sure that's a bad workaround, but it worked for the use case.

Comment: I do not see at all how this is answering the question.